# How to implement multiple categories in a Java data structure?

Tags: java, android, data-structures

I'm trying to implement categories for a mock food delivery app in android.

I want to have categories for a restaurant like burgers, pizza, etc. Within each there might be any number of food items. And these restaurants would include n categories. How do I implement something like this?

For now, the data will be hardcoded into the program for just a proof of concept so please do not include databases as I'm still learning android and am not very familiar with SQLite or FireBase, etc.

Comment: I would probably go with the following. There is a food class, in it is a category enum. Then you can store everything in a list. To get items of one category, just filter the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how you want to access the data. You can make `Category` an Enum and assign it to `FoodItem`, then have `Restaurant` have an ArrayList of `FoodItems`.

OR

You can make `Category` a class with an ArrayList of `FoodItems`, and have `Restaurant` have an ArrayList of `Categories`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your concept, it looks like you're going to integrate any Web API *(REST or anything else like firebase)* to fetch data from Web Servers.

I would suggest to do the following:

1. Create a **.json file** having your content that you might need to display.
2. Make some **model data classes** related to your **.json file** that needed to be parsed.
3. Now, read your .json file temporarily from assets folder to get content most out of it *(then display it in your app)*.

In such a way, if you've to do some **JSON parsing** in nearer future, you'll already have all stuffs needed to parse that JSON *(like your Data Transfer Objects **DTOs**)* and code for parsing as well.

So at that time, all you'll have to do is integrate some HTTP client and setup end point because, you're already having JSON parsing at your end or setting up with Firebase *(Rest of stuffs are already handled)*.